# Deforming a basis of a polynomial ring

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, schur-functions

The ring $Symm$ of symmetric functions in infinitely many variables is well-known to be a polynomial ring in the elementary symmetric functions, and has a $\mathbb Z$-basis of Schur functions $\{S_\lambda\}$, with structure constants $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$ called Littlewood-Richardson numbers.

I have been studying a commutative deformation of these structure constants, i.e. lifting $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$ to a 2-variable polynomial $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu(a,b)$, for which I have a very explicit formula (much too complicated to describe here). However, since $Symm$ is a polynomial ring (i.e. free), any commutative deformation of it must be trivializable: there must be a way to deform each $S_\lambda$ to a function $S_\lambda(a,b)$ whose ordinary multiplication has my structure constants.

> Given the $\{c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu(a,b)\}$, how can I trivialize this family, finding such deformations $S_\lambda(a,b)$?

It seems like the answer should be nonunique (hence harder to find); it's easy to imagine deformations of the basis that don't change the structure constants at all.

> What extra conditions should one put on the deformation in order to make the trivialization unique?

Comment: Is it possible that the deformation is upper-triangular (i.e. that $S_\lambda(a,b) = S_\lambda + \textrm{lower order terms}$)? How complicated are the structure constants when $\mu$ is 1 box?

Comment: I think $a=0$ is triangular one way, $b=0$ triangular the other way. The one-box rule is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88569/deformation-of-the-product-of-symmetric-functions